# MonoGame Mac MonoGame Templates Installation

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xna, monodevelop

Does anyone know how to add the MonoGame templates to MonoDevelop on mac? I followed the instructions in the readme file and added the MononDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 to the addins folder located in MonoDevelop.app, but I cannot find the template anywhere in MonoDevelop. Where should I be looking? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Old question, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928367/how-do-i-add-monogame-project-templates-to-monodevelop-on-macos links to http://infinitespace-studios.co.uk/2012/08/02/getting-started-with-monogame-for-mac-osx/, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The latest that I read was that they currently have functioning templates for Windows and Linux, but not Mac :( Getting a basic project up and running was quite the ordeal for me, so [I posted the template that I use](https://github.com/danielellis/MonoGame-MacGame). It's very raw and you'll probably need to fix the references to the MonoGame projects themselves (as well as install all the prerequesites [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials%3aInstalling-Prerequisites-on-MacOS-for-MonoMac-project), but it should be a good baseline.

Comment: What version of mono and monogame are you using? I tried the template but I got a bunch of compile errors.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment I got rid of the errors. Now it just says "Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any ideas?

Comment: Is the error coming from the template or the MonoGame library itself?

Comment: The error does not give any details as to file or line. It simply says "Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the bottom left corner of MonoDevelop when I try and build the solution.