# How do I add MonoGame project templates to MonoDevelop on MacOS?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monogame

According to the readme, I am supposed to

> 1. Shutdown MonoDevelop
> 2. Find your MonoDevelop AppBundle
> 3. Right Click on it and select "Show package Contents"
> 4. Press Alt and Drag and Drop the directory MonoDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 into ../Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/

Which I did - but I still don't see the project templates in MonoDevelop. I also looked at these other questions [here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/258939/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508349/monogame-mac-templates-installation) and a few more on google - but didn't find that anyone got the templates to work (most of them used workarounds that involved hand-editing other such [template projects](https://github.com/danielellis/MonoGame-MacGame) or editing a MonoTouch OpenGL project).

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question very is outdated and without answers, is unlikely to be helpful to anyone in the future.